# NSPredicate filter array

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

How can I use NSPredicate to filter an array where the object in the array's ->_title variable is equal to the variable title? I tried the following below, but it doesn't filter anything out.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[posts mutableCopy] autorelease];
NSString *title = [[TBForrstr sharedForrstr] stringForPostType:type];
[array filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF->_title == %@", title]]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the title matches exactly in the array.  Or, if you want to be more flexible, make it case-insensitive:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[posts mutableCopy] autorelease];
NSString *title = [[TBForrstr sharedForrstr] stringForPostType:type];
[array filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"_title == [cd]%@", title]];
```

Comment: the `stringWithFormat:` isn't really necessary, just use the `predicateWithFormat:` directly!

Comment: My bad.  Copy/pasted :D.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This one is working for me - notice the single quotes around the string:

```
NSArray *posts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Cat or dog?", @"_title", nil],
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"I saved a file, where is it?", @"_title", nil],
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"How should I do this?", @"_title", nil],
nil];

NSMutableArray *array = [[posts mutableCopy] autorelease];
NSString *title = @"Cat or dog?";
[array filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF._title == '%@'", title]]];

NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like:

```
[NSPRedicate predicateWithFormat:@"title LIKE %@",title]
```

The title should be matched to your _title ivar via KVC

Comment: what does this have to do with public? but I guess it's just title LIKE %@ and not _title. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172-BAJEAIEE